# stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) returns Optional in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to solve the following issues using Swift:

1) Optional?
Instead of returning "1%20Market%20Street,%20San%20Francisco,%20CA%2094107" as I would like, why is the following code returning "Optional("1%20Market%20Street,%20San%20Francisco,%20CA%2094107")"

```
println("\(address.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))")
```

2) How do I replace commas with %2C?

Answer (score 2):

1)

Use either

```
println("\(address.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)")
```

Notice the `!` - it extracts the optional value.

Or

```
if let str = address.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    println(str)
}
```

2)

You can use something like:

```
let stringWithCommas = "Hello,World"
let stringWithReplacedCommas = stringWithCommas.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",", withString: "%2C", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
  let tempString: String? = "1%20Market%20Street,%20San%20Francisco,%20CA%2094107"
if tempString != nil
{
    let newString = tempString!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",", withString: "%2C", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
}
```

It returns optional,because sometimes this method return nil.

Answer (score 0):

1.Yes it returns optional value as it can return nil value which is optional in Swift to know more about optional values in detail read following post [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/understanding-optionals-swift)

```
var newString = String()

if let optionalString = newString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
{
   newString = "1%20Market%20Street,%20San%20Francisco,%20CA%2094107"
}

// 2. To replace , with %2C 

newString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",", withString: "%2C", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```