# Cannot assign UIImage from NSURL because of string encoding

Tags: ios, swift

This is my simple `UIImageView` extension:

```
extension UIImageView {

    func setImageWithString(string: String?) {

        if let string = string, let url = NSURL(string: string) {
            sd_setImageWithURL(url)
        }
    }
}
```

And for the following string I cannot get inside condition:

```
"http://posbistro-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/location_images/images/116/2fa/ad-/medium/Bez tytułu.jpg"
```

How can I workaround this?

Comment: Have you tried something with url percentage encoding (stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding) ? take a look at this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353388/stringbyaddingpercentescapesusingencodingnsutf8stringencoding-returns-optional

Comment: try to encode your url, like: `let encodedPath = string.URLString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do like

```
func setImageWithString(stringbyName: String?) {

     let urlStr = stringbyName.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(. URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())

    if let  url = NSURL(string: urlStr) {
        sd_setImageWithURL(url)
    }
}
```

or use like

```
   func setImageWithString(stringbyName: String?) {

     let urlStr = stringbyName.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    if let  url = NSURL(string: urlStr) {
        sd_setImageWithURL(url)
    }
}
```

for additional information see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32242712/replacement-for-stringbyaddingpercentescapesusingencoding-in-ios9/32599409)

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk - can you update the question once plz

Comment: the second works, but is deprecated... is it workaround for this?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk - that the reason I added the first choice , I think you need to change the type of `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet` or `URLHostAllowedCharacterSet` else try once you get answewr

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk - sure

Comment: Thank you, the first one with `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet` worked fine:)